# Django Site matching query error when start

Tags: django

Error: DoesNotExist at /login/
Site matching query does not exist.

Git code: https://github.com/Vladislava05/todo.git

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to your question?

Comment: It is full traceback that I see when I try to start

Comment: Matching query DoesNotExist usually indicates a view isn't being called properly, or perhaps it doesn't exist. Full traceback is what you see either when you start, or when the bugs appear and code stops working, which is the start in your case.